# Issue with binding WPF DataGrid Combobox columns using ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Getting issue when binding WPF Combobox columns using the following Model:

```
public class Game
{
    public string Name;
    ObservableCollection<Player> Players{get; set;}
}

public class Player
{
    public int ID;
    public string PlayerName;

    public List<string> AllSelectionStatus = new List<string> {"Yes", "No", "Waiting"};

    public string PlayerSelectionStatus;
}

public class PlayerModel
{
    ObservableCollection<Game> Games  {get; set;}
}
```

I need to display the above structure as shown below in a WPF DataGrid.

[image]

Each combobox 'ItemSource' Property Value is set with AllSelectionStatus and 'SelectedItem' Property Value is set wth PlayerSelectionStatus.
Here is my XAML code.

```
<DataGrid Name="dgRowDetails" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Black" SelectionMode="Single" HeadersVisibility="Column"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Games[0].Players}">
<DataGrid.Resources>
<Style x:Key="DataGridComboBoxColumnStyle0" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseComboBoxBoxStyle}" TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding AllSelectionStatus, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding PlayerSelectionStatus, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />

    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSystemEnabled}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
    </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="DataGridComboBoxColumnStyle1" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseComboBoxBoxStyle}" TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding AllSelectionStatus,  Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding PlayerSelectionStatus, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSystemEnabled}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
    </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
<!-- The 3rd Combobox style not shown as it is similar to the one above-->
</Style>
```

The issue with this XAML is, the Game2 & Game3 comboboxes are not having their own PlayerSelectionStatus. Both Game2 & Game3 are getting Game1 PlayerSelectionStatus.

Need help to resolve this. Appreciate your help.

Comment: move selecteditem out of the style

Comment: Tried. Not working.

Comment: Your code seems incomplete. You need to provide us with [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to be able to help you. My instinct, based on your comment on the answer below, is your data-structure is wrong even. But probably the biggest problem is you trying to work with Autogenerated columns & dynamic set of columns. Datagrid doesn't support this (though it can be made to work). You'll have easier time displaying 1 Game per row and then bindings will start making easier sense too.

Comment: If you'd like to discuss this in detail (and have enough source code to share), you can come over to us @ [WPF Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf) and we can help you figure things out (and eventually post a final answer back here for future folks)

Comment: Solved the issue by just creating one flat collection instead of two.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` to `false` inside your `ComboBox` styles.

```
<Setter Property="IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem" Value="False"/>
```

---

For your example it should be:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgRowDetails" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Black" SelectionMode="Single" HeadersVisibility="Column"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Games[0].Players}">
<DataGrid.Resources>
<Style x:Key="DataGridComboBoxColumnStyle0" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseComboBoxBoxStyle}" TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding AllSelectionStatus, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding PlayerSelectionStatus, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <Setter Property="IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem" Value="False"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />

    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSystemEnabled}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
    </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="DataGridComboBoxColumnStyle1" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseComboBoxBoxStyle}" TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding AllSelectionStatus,  Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding PlayerSelectionStatus, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <Setter Property="IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem" Value="False"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSystemEnabled}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
    </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
<!-- The 3rd Combobox style not shown as it is similar to the one above-->
</Style>
```

Comment: setting IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem to false is not helping. Still the combo boxes in the Game2 & Game3 columns are displaying Game1 combobox data.

Answer (score 0):

The ItemSource of your datagrid is only the first Game,

```
    ItemsSource="{Binding Games[0].Players}
```

and each game object only has one PlayerSelectionStatus, which is bound to all three comboboxes. Nothing is bound to Games[1] or Games[2], or the complete PlayerModel Games list.

I think you need to rethink your datastructure, so that each player has a list of games (or three Game properties), each with it's own status.